# Input to the arraylist with Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, arraylist, input, thymeleaf

I have simple class that contains 2 `String`s, 1 `Integer` and 1 `ArrayList<String>`. Using Spring MVC and Thymeleaf I'm trying to craete a form, where I can insert data to create an object. Sadly I have no idea how to handle `Arraylist`. This is what I've got so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>F O R M</h1>
<form th:action="@{/form/person}" th:object="${person}" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Name:</td>
      <td><input type="text" th:field="*{name}"/></td>
      <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}">Name error</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Age:</td>
      <td><input type="number" th:field="*{age} "/></td>
      <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('age')}" th:errors="*{age}">Age Error</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>City:</td>
      <td><input type="text" th:field="*{city}"/></td>
      <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('city')}" th:errors="*{city}">City Error</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
      <td><input type="reset" value="Reset"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For example if your list name is `city` then:

```
 <input type="text" th:field="*{city[__${INDEX}__]}" />
```

Where `INDEX` is index in your list. When for example you just put String on the second index then on the first index you will have `null`.

Comment: let's assume that my arraylist<String> is for nicknames (and class is Person.class). Everyone can have a lot of nicknames, is there any way to add nicknames in simple form.html, using SpEL?

Comment: @ogarogar I don't know to much about SpEL so I can't help you with that. Do you wan't to let user to add as many nicknames as he wants?  Why don't you add for example just 3 input fields for nicknames?